Is it possible to automate the data mining process to automatically generate insights
I'm a Frontend Dev tasked with Data Insights (Help!) Hey everyone!
I'm a fresh graduate working as a front-end developer. This is my first real job, and I'm thrown into the deep end a bit! My first task is to figure out a way to automatically generate insights from a dataset.
It doesn't necessarily need to be super insightful, just something.
I'm coming from a pure front-end background, so data analysis is new territory for me. Any advice on how to approach this task would be greatly appreciated!
Here's what I know:
I need to work with a dataset related to schools (but I don't have details yet on the format or size). I need to automatically generate some kind of insights from the data. The "usefulness" of the insights isn't critical at this stage, I just need to generate a lot of insights and later decide if they are useful or not.
For example:-
there are 14 students whose name starts with A
there are 23 students that live in this area, etc
Here's what I'm hoping to learn:
Are there any common tools or libraries that can help with this task? What's a good starting point for exploring a dataset without any prior experience?

Unless you can use AI, the answer is no.  You have to write the code for a specific sets of KPIs. The only tool I have seen at a University, where its not for sale, it selects 3 fields from the database (at random) and plots them.  The plot rotates and the operator spots regions of one colour and records those combinations.

Thank you for your response! I appreciate your input. Just to clarify, I am allowed to use AI tools for this task, but I need to ensure that the data remains secure and is not sent over through an API. Given this constraint, do you have any suggestions for AI tools or libraries that could help @RohitGupta
